# Flutter: Compilation issues with the packages Freezed and json_serializable

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) with [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable). I am using the below versions

```
freezed: ^0.9.2
json_serializable: ^3.2.5
freezed_annotation: ^0.7.1
```

My freezed class looks like this

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'freezed_classes.freezed.dart';

@freezed
abstract class User with _$User {
  factory User(
      {@required String uid,
      String firstName,
      String lastName,
      String email,
      Map<int, String> pictures
      }) = _User;

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);
}
```

I am using this to generate the classes

```
flutter pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

The command seems to execute successfully, but my IDE seems to throw these compilation issues

```
error: The method '_$_$_UserFromJson' isn't defined for the class '_$_User'. (undefined_method at  lib/freezed/freezed_classes.freezed.dart:68)
error: The method '_$_$_UserToJson' isn't defined for the class '_$_User'. (undefined_method at  lib/freezed/freezed_classes.freezed.dart:156)
```

Any idea why this might be happening ?

I tried a flutter clean and IDE restart, but this persists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per `freezed` documentation:

```
The changes necessary to make it compatible with json_serializable consists of two lines:

a new part: part 'model.g.dart';
a new constructor on the targeted class: factory Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ModelFromJson(json);
```

You are missing the `part` required for `json_serializable`: `part freezed_classes.g.dart`

Comment: ah, completely missed that. Thanks for your help :)